# If statement in batch

Tags: batch-file

whatever I insert as docopy, the program always copies files from source to destination. **Does anyone know how to fix it?** *I want to copy files after inserting 'y' and skip it if 'n' is inserted*. Of course, I tried if else statement, but it didn't work properly too. After all, program should ask what part of file to rename.
I'm sure it's easy for You :)

```
set source="C:\Users\Desktop\Basic"
set destination="C:\Users\Desktop\CopyofBasic"
set renfiles="C:\Users\Desktop\CopyofBasic"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


set /p docopy="Do You want to copy files? [Y/N]: "

if /i %%docopy%% == "%y%" (
    goto :makecopy
    )
if /i %%docopy%% == "%n%" (
    goto :nagative
    )

:makecopy
    xcopy /s /v /h /k /z %source% %destination%
    goto :renfiles
:negative
    echo None files are copied.
    goto :renfiles

:renfiles
cd %renfiles%
set /p var1="Insert part of filename to replace it: "
set /p var2="Insert new part of filename: "
set /p var3="Insert files fomrat: "

for /r %%G in (%var3%) do (
    set "filename=%%~nxG"
    ren "%%G" "!filename:%var1%=%var2%!"
)

echo Filenames have been already changed.
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems:

- the conditions are incorrect:

  ```
  if /i %%docopy%% == "%y%"
  ```

  when `docopy` was having a value of *n* was evaluating to: `if /I %docopy% == "" (goto :makecopy )` which was false so it was skipped. Same thing happened with the next condition, so the next "instruction" in the batch file was the `:makecopy` label.
- typo `goto:nagative` (nAgative)

How the conditions should look like: use `"` (or `[`,`]`) as variable guards, but not `%`):

```
if /i "%docopy%" == "y" (
    goto :makecopy
    )
if /i "%docopy%" == "n" (
    goto :negative
    )
```

@Edit1: Corrected the condition evaluation as @aschipfl noticed.

Comment: No, `if /i %%docopy%% == "%y%"` is evaluated to `if /i %docopy% == ""`; `%%docopy%%` becomes the literal string `%docopy%` due to the double-`%`-signs, and `"%y%"` becomes `""` as a variable `y` is not defined... generally, I recommend to always use `""` in order to avoid trouble with special characters like `&`, `^`, `<`, `>`, `|`...

Comment: You are correct @aschipfl, thank you for spotting it. I copy/pasted the evaluation string from the wrong program run (an intermediate state after I did some changes of my own).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `choice` and testing the `errorlevel` instead of `set /p`

http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html

```
CHOICE /M Do you want to copy files? [Y/N] 
IF errorlevel 2 goto nagative
IF errorlevel 1 goto makecopy
```